# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting the below when doing a JQUERY ajax call in jsfiddle

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404

URL works fine when I put it in a browser?

Does not work in JsFiddle?

```
var URL="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json&q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22ACM%22)%0A%09%09";
$.get(URL).done(function (data) {
    alert("HELLO");
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("NOPE");
}).always(function () {
    alert("OH WELLL");
});
```

Comment: And what happened when you looked up the error and tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @Anonymous I made a stack overflow question....that's what happened

Comment: The URL gives me a 404 when I try it.

Comment: yahooapis supports CORS, as Juhana says, the URL is not valid

Comment: Does noone read the comments ?

Comment: Even if the the URL was correct, what exactly is it that you do not understand? Isn't the message clear?

Comment: whoa whoa....that URL was just working a sec ago.....

Comment: *"URL works fine when I put it in a browser?"* Apparently that's not the case.

Comment: I think the first `&` in the URL should be `?`.

Comment: ok disregard...that url is adding quotes to parms behind the scenes

Comment: @Juhana - it is, I just posted that, but you post it as an answer, you were faster

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem on both JSFiddle and Codepen. I needed to load an external js-data file and it was blocked due to browser-security. My workaround was to include the whole js-data as script with HTML in the header:

```html
<script src="http://yoururlto/yourdata.js"></script>
```

The data js itself looks like this:

```js
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
                }]
};
```

Then access the data in any way you want:

```js
geojsonLayer.addData(data);
map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a standard CORS response when an XHR call is made from the browser. The server needs to allow the domain/location of the browser to make requests.

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Otherwise, the server will block incoming requests.

Another way to get around this is to use a known server as a proxy to make requests to the external API.

Answer (score -1):

It's because your API does not return a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header. This header can restrict what hosts to allow access to that specific page and this behaviour is embedded in the XMLHttpRequest functions that jQuery uses. It's used as security measure so there isn't really a workaround for it.